# Oozie shell Action - Running hive from shell issue

Tags: shell, hadoop, hive, oozie

Based on a condition being true I am executing hive -e   in shell script.It works fine.When I put this script in Shell action in Oozie and run ,I get a scriptName.sh: line 42: hive:command not found exception.

I tried passing the < env-var >PATH=/usr/lib/hive< /env-var> in the shell action, but I guess I am making some mistake there,because I get  the same error scriptName.sh: line 42: hive:command not found

**Edited:**
I used `which hive` in the shell script. Its output is not consistent.I get two variations of output :
1. `/usr/bin/hive` along with a `Delegation token can be issued only with kerberos or web authentication` Java IOException."

2.`which : hive not in {.:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:...}`

Comment: You are on the right track.  You are missing environment variables.  shells will show you a complete list of your variables with the set command.  I believe oozie runs in a separate context, so it may have different settings from you shell command line.

Comment: One problem was that the environment variable PATH of Oozie is getting substituted by my entry in <env-var>...I copied the Oozie PATH variable value and appended :/usr/lib/hive to it..Even then I get the same error..

Comment: It is NOT JUST one variable that is the problem.  At the command line type the command set.  set displays all variables.  Work though which ones you need to have to get your setup to work for oozie.

Comment: Ok..Does the script need execute permission? because even when i give it execute permission and put it in HDFS before executing it in Oozie,that permission is lost.I cant do a chmod +x on it too..

Answer (score 6):

Ok finally I figured it out .Might be a trivial thing for experts on Shell but can help someone starting out.

**1. hive : command not found**        It was not a classpath issue.It was a shell issue.The environment i am running in is a korn shell (echo $SHELL to find out). But the hive script(/usr/lib/hive/bin/hive.sh) is a bash shell.So i changed the shebang (#! /bin/bash) in my script and it worked.

**2.Delegation Token can only be issued with kerberos or web authentication.**
In my hive script i added `SET mapreduce.job.credentials.binary = ${HADOOP_TOKEN_FILE_LOCATION}` HADOOP_TOKEN_FILE_LOCATION is a variable that holds the location of jobToken.This token needs to be passed for authentication of access to HDFS data(in my case,an HDFS read operation,through Hive Select query) in a secure cluster.[Know more on Delegation Token Here](http://hortonworks.com/blog/the-role-of-delegation-tokens-in-apache-hadoop-security/) .

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but i am still unable to get past "hive:command not found exception."  any pointers how to debug this?

Comment: This is because the shell action can be run by Oozie on any of the data nodes . The hive cli is guaranteed to run only on the edgenode and not on all data nodes .So I got "hive:command not found" when Oozie ran the shell script on the node which does not have hive . Its not a good practice to run hive (or any application that is supposed to be present only on the edgenode of hadoop) from shell .

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, u miss shell environment variables.

To confirm it, use `export` in called shell by oozie.

If u use oozie call shell, a simple way is use `/bin/bash -l your_script`.

PS. PATH is a list of directories, so u need append `${HIVE_HOME}/bin` to your PATH not `${HIVE_HOME}/bin/hive`.